# Install Rapidjson in lua zerobrane studio

Tags: zerobrane

How can i install - import the rapidjson module into Zerobrane studio?
i downloaded the luarocks, and runs the luarocks install rapidjson

C:\Users\ODYSSEY\Desktop\ZeroBraneStudio>luarocks install rapidjson
Installing https://luarocks.org/rapidjson-0.6.1-1.src.rock

Error: Failed finding Lua header files. You may need to install them or configure LUA_INCDIR.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem with luarocks, not ZeroBrane Studio. You need to configure LUA_INCDIR environmental variable to point to the location of Lua header files (those are usually inside `src/` folder of the Lua package).

There is nothing special you need to do to use rapidjson (or any other module) with ZeroBrane Studio. If you can run your script from a particular folder and the module is found because you configured the environmental variables or set up package.path/.cpath values, then you should be able to run it from the IDE by setting up the project directory (`Project > Project Directory > Choose...`) to the same location.